# How to implement default of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

How can I implement the protocol above to my existing viewcontroller with default implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A protocol is a way of influencing the actions of another class's instance or getting told when another class's instance is about to do something, is doing something or has done something.

To change the behaviour of an instance of that class, you can assign an object, sometimes the object that instantiates the class, to be its delegate and then, when the instance gets to a point where you can influence it or it wants to let you know about something it will check to see if it has a delegate and then see if that delegate even wants that message (i.e. if the delegate implements that delegate method). If both are true then the message defined in the protocol is sent.

the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol has 5 you can implement:

**Responding to Changes**

```
– controllerWillChangeContent:
– controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
– controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:
– controllerDidChangeContent:
```

**Customizing Section Names**

```
– controller:sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:
```

None of these are `@required` to implement the protocol so if you say your class conforms to `<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>` then the "default implementation" is to not implement any of those methods, but you might as well not set a delegate at all in that case.

If you give some more detail about what you want to accomplish maybe we can help you more.

Comment: Classes don't have delegates. The instance will check whether it has a delegate and try to send messages to it.

Comment: @PeterHosey Yup. I clarified it. I didn't want to just say object as I was trying to reinforce how protocols help you "alter" other classes without having to subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit unclear to me -- jackslash's answer is one way to interpret "default implementation" (and a good answer for that). But I suspect you might instead mean something to the effect of, "How do I implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol such that the user sees the same standard table view behaviors (e.g. animations for edit, delete, insert, reorder) found in other apps?"

If that's the case... indeed, it's not completely straightforward from the protocol documentation where to go if you're starting from scratch.

But you don't have to start from scratch. I'd recommend looking into the code you get straight from the templates in Xcode 4.3: make a new app using the **Master-Detail Application** template and be sure to check **Use Core Data**, and the project will contain a table view controller whose implementation of the protocol might well handle everything you'll ever need.

Again, going into a little more detail about what results you're after, and what avenues you've explored already, helps us better answer your questions.